# Kubernetes + Docker container pod on AKS blocking external endpoint

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

We have an AKS cluster on Azure and an endpoint on Azure App Service.

Calls are being initiated from a service (exposing a deployed app) on AKS to an App on Azure App Service (Public URL)

When deploying to Azure App Service, the application goes down in order to deploy, meanwhile calls are still being initiated from the AKS micro-service.

The AKS service starts throwing exceptions that the endpoint is not available which is normal. but when the Azure App service is up again the AKS service still throws the same error even when the app is online again and serving other services successfully. it is like the AKS is caching the error.

In order to fix it I have to kill all the living pods of the faulty micro-service and then scaling it back out again.

Can someone please guide me on why is this happening and how can I prevent this in future deployments?

Comment: this has nothing to do with kubernetes, you need to fix your microservice to retry properly

Comment: @4c74356b41 thank you for the reply, I will check with the development team

Comment: @4c74356b41 is right about microservices issue, but if you want to handle it on pod level, you can add pod liveliness probe to service url (Public URL) and set max retries, pod will hit that url and if fails, it will retry max no of times.

Comment: Do you solve the issue with the comment? If yes, please add an answer to show the solution.